# Questions regarding the command: “net use * http://myserver.com”

Tags: iis, file-upload, security, webdav

Apparently I'm able to `net use * http://servername.com` and this concept is completely new to me.

Does this mean I'm using WebDAV?

What are the security implications?

How can I read/write files in this manner?

Why doesn't it work for every website?

Is it possible to write files using this method?

Comment: This may be better served on SuperUser or ServerFault

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. After this net use statement, you can **read** regular http content as though it were files on your local disk.

For writing/random access and "dir" support, the website needs to implement additional webdav commands.